# Do partial row in BigQuery to get last data and order by id

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-order-by, partitioning

i want to get last `id` and their `rank` (based on `order by` `date_update` `asc` and then `order by` again by id `desc` ) and show `id` and `rank` of id. i do the query like below:

```
 SELECT id as data,
                    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_update) AS rank
                    FROM `test.sample`
                    ORDER BY id DESC
                    LIMIT 1
```

and it's work for other table but didn't work some table with large data and get notice:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.
```

i have done read [Troubleshooting Error Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors)
and try to remove `ORDER BY` but still can't running, what should i do ?

sample data:

```
id     date_update
22     2019-10-04
14     2019-10-01
24     2019-10-03
13     2019-10-02
```

process :

1. `Rank() Over (Order by date_update)`

id   date_update rank

```
14   2019-10-01    1
13   2019-10-02    2
24   2019-10-03    3
22   2019-10-04    4
```

2. `order by id desc` based on above

   ```
   id    date_update  rank                                            
   24   2019-10-03   3
   22   2019-10-04   4
   14   2019-10-01   1
   13   2019-10-02   2
   ```

this is the expected result:

```
id        rank                                                         
24         3
```

Comment: You have 2 `ORDER BY`, one in window function, the other one's before LIMIT 1. It is hard to believe you still receive the error if you removed both ones.

Comment: You may create separate question about the nature of your query/expected results and get help on how to achieve your goal with SQL.

Comment: i want to get last data in big query table @YunZhang , i used last data as flag to update new data in big query. any idea to fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the query below. It basically finds the row with max ID (latest ID), then queries the source table again using date_value of max id row as a filter.

```
WITH 
`test.sample` AS
(
  select 22 AS id, DATE('2019-10-04') as date_update union all
  select 14 AS id, DATE('2019-10-01') as date_update union all
  select 24 AS id, DATE('2019-10-03') as date_update union all
  select 13 AS id, DATE('2019-10-02') as date_update 
),
max_id_row AS
(
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, date_update) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] vals
    FROM `test.sample`
)
SELECT m.vals.id, m.vals.date_update, COUNT(*) as rank
FROM `test.sample` as t
JOIN max_id_row as m
    ON t.date_update <= m.vals.date_update
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: thanks @Sab ! it's work, but how the query to get `id` and `rank` based on latest `date_update` and `id` ? i have edit the question above.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly, can you please provide a sample data and example output? @Nadyaf

Comment: I fixed it now, so you can use the new version.

Comment: thank u @Sab , `id` , `date_update` was correct ! but `rank` is failed, i have done give the sample data, process, and expected result clearly on above

Comment: I updated my query again, including your data. And I hope it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and should scale to whatever "large" data you have

```
#standardSQL
SELECT b.id, COUNT(1) + 1 AS `rank`
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
JOIN (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, date_update) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
) b
ON a.date_update < b.date_update
GROUP BY id
```

If to apply for sample data in your question -

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 22 id, DATE '2019-10-04' date_update UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, '2019-10-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 24, '2019-10-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, '2019-10-02' 
)
```

result is

```
Row id  rank     
1   24  3
```

The "trick" here is in changing focus from not scalable code with non or badly parallelized operations (RANK) to something that is as simple as COUNT'ing

So, your case (at least as it is presented in question's "process" section) can be rephrased as finding number of rows before the day with highest id - that simple  - thus above simple query. Obviously adding "1" to that count gives you exactly what would RANK gave you if worked

Comment: Amazing ! it's work for me correctly ! thanks for the suggestions, i'm never used `COUNT(1)` or `ARRAY_AGG` before, i'll learn again! @Mikhail